# Substring a statement after character matching and year

Tags: r, substring, datefilter

I am trying to extract certain rows based on year from my dataset, furthermore I want to substring those rows matching the following conditions, for year 2017 I want to substring the the portion before the second '-' in the statment for eg: "17Q4-EMEA-All-SOV-OutR-Sov_Score-18Dec.Email" I would want only "All-SOV-OutR-Sov_Score-18Dec.Email" and for 2018 I want to remove the portion after the '.' for eg: "**IVP Program Template**.IVP Email Template" I want "**IVP Program Template**"

I have tried using

```
data$col <- sub(".*:", "", data$`Email Name`)
data$col2 <- substring(data$`Email Name`, regexpr(".", data$`Email Name`) + 1)
```

but none of it is working and returns the statements as is, also for filtering based on year I tried using the filter function 
`filter(data, as.Date(data$`First Activity (EDT)`) = "2017")` but it gives me syntax error

My dataset is like this:
[image]

Comment: Please provide data with `dput(head(df,n))` not images or links.

Comment: And please provide the expected output.

Comment: here is my dataset: structure(list(`Email Name` = c("**IVP Program Template**.IVP Email Template", 
"17Q4-EMEA-All-SOV-Global Borrowing_5March18.Email", "17Q4-EMEA-All-SOV-OutR-Sov_Score-18Dec.Email", 
"17Q4-EMEA-All-SOV-Social Housing_8March1.Email", "17Q4-EMEA-Insurance-Personalised.PersonalisedFI&INS"
), `First Activity (EDT)` = structure(c(12/19/2017,3/5/2018,12/18/2017, 3/9/2018, 12/14/2017), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the data, rather than putting it into a comment. In addition to being very hard to read, the comment box interprets and formats the text you put in, which changes it and makes it impossible to reproduce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the regex that should give you the desired result for 2017 values:

```
sub(".*?-.*?-", "", "17Q4-EMEA-All-SOV-OutR-Sov_Score-18Dec.Email")
# "All-SOV-OutR-Sov_Score-18Dec.Email"
```

The one for 2018 values:

```
sub("\\..*", "", "IVP Program Template.IVP Email Template")
# IVP Program Template
```

You can then apply the regex functions with `ifelse`:

```
library(lubridate)

data$email_adj <- NA

data$email_adj <- ifelse(year(mdy(data$`First Activity (EDT)`)) %in% "2017", sub(".*?-.*?-", "", data$`Email Name`), data$email_adj)

data$email_adj <- ifelse(year(mdy(data$`First Activity (EDT)`)) %in% "2018", sub("\\..*", "", data$`Email Name`), data$email_adj)
```

If you want to filter by month instead of year use the `month` instaed of the `year` function (in the example I only selected months from April until July):

```
library(lubridate)

data$email_adj <- NA

data$email_adj <- ifelse(month(mdy(data$`First Activity (EDT)`)) %in% 4:7, sub(".*?-.*?-", "", data$`Email Name`), data$email_adj)

data$email_adj <- ifelse(month(mdy(data$`First Activity (EDT)`)) %in% 4:7, sub("\\..*", "", data$`Email Name`), data$email_adj)
```

Comment: hi, this works fine for year, but actually I have to do it for certain number of months, like april to july. so I am doing something like this            data$newCol <- ifelse(data[months(data$`First Activity (EDT)`) %in% month.name[4:7], ], sub(".*?-.*?-", "", data$`Email Name`), data$`Email Name`) however I get an error, can you please help me correct this syntax

Comment: I adjusted the answer to account for this issue